# Stress testing webpage, server program

Tags: php, testing, stress-testing

Right now, on *Localhost*, i've got a streaming web page set up. (its streaming a desktop from my other computer). Right now *i'm not using* unique ip for viewer counter, because i want to stress test my server.

**Basically** i want to fake "new tabs" (*viewers*) of a browser.

I want to know how much my server can handle right now before going live.

So **any** ideas would be welcome how to do it. 
Any programming language will suit me.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically i want to fake "new tabs" (viewers) of a browser.

Below code makes use of plain JS, that opens a tab in your browser every minute. Adjust the time as per your needs.

```
window.onload = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    window.open( "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" );
  }, 60000) // 1 min
};
```